# gdal_calc works but I get a Python error at the end of each process?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, osgeo4w

I have a problem while using gdal_calc by a .bat file.
Here is the code :

> call "C:\OSGeo4w64\bin\o4w_env.bat"
>   gdal_calc -A"D:\tuilage_script_1\tuilage\ndvi\4_810000_6370000_820000_6360000_ndvi.tif" --calc="A" --outfile="D:\tuilage_script_1\tuilage\ndvi\test_gdal_cal3.tif"

It first loads OSGEO environment, then it copies the input raster "A" in an output raster "outfile". The operation is done, but I get the following error messsage : "Python has stopped working", see picture enclosed

[image: Screenshot]

I already read this topic :
[GDAL_CALC works but I get a python error at the end of each process that prevents automation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101921/gdal-calc-works-but-i-get-a-python-error-at-the-end-of-each-process-that-prevent)

But the solution doesn't fit with the aim of my batch file that must be automated to be run from an office basic script for more than 100 operations.

I am using 1.11.2 Gdal version with 2.8 Qgis Wien, 2.7 Python version on Windows-7.

Comment: I sometimes had problems with rasters because there wasn't an **existing .tif file**. Perhaps create a blank .tif file with the same name and location of the output file and run the script again?

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for you help! I have  tried  but now it doesn't even make the operation. I have" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for : *: 'NoneType and 'in'" an I also have the MsgBox "Python has stopped working". I even have this message when I call gdal_calc -help from Osfeo command line

Comment: Osgeo command line*

Comment: Hopefully others can advise on this issue as I have barely used gdal operations. Also, I'm not sure why you're receiving an _operand error_ considering there's no multiplication symbol ( * ) in your above code.

Comment: Ok.  Probably because I get get this first ouputfile from a r.mapcalc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but this might be caused by the version conflict of the linked C runtime dlls between gdal111.dll and python bindings. [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) shows that gdal111.dll is linked to msvcr100.dll, whereas _gdal.pyd is linked to msvcr90.dll. Opening a ticket in OSGeo4W bug tracker is a good idea.

Comment: Oh. Ok Thanks. By the way, I have also tryied on Qgis 2.4, Gdal 1.11.0 and it's the same. I am going to open this ticket. Thanks!