# gdal writeArray causes appcrash at end of python script

Tags: python, gdal, error, osgeo4w

i'm using OSGeo4W64 (gdal 2.0.2-8) with Python 2.7.5 on Windows 8.1 64bit.
Editor is PyCharm 2016.1.2.

I want to save an image with gdal, but i always get an error when the python script is complete. The following example causes the error:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

path = 'D:\\test.tiff'
data = np.array([[1]])   
sizeY = int(data.shape[0])
sizeX = int(data.shape[1])
bandCount = 1
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

dataSet = driver.Create(path, sizeX, sizeY, bandCount, gdal.GDT_Byte)
band = dataSet.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray(data)  # causes error, if commented out, everything is fine

band = None
dataSet = None

print "the appcrash will come next"
```

I'm dereferencing the vars and it should be fine, but i'm getting "python.exe has stopped working".

The console shows:

```
the appcrash will come next

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

When i run the code in QGIS (2.14.1) and i close QGIS, a similar error occurrs and a dump file was created.

```
Process Name:   qgis-bin.exe : C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin.exe
Process Architecture:   x64
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information:  The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual 
address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
```

My GDAL-Enviroment-Vars are:

```
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins
GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGEO4~1\share\gdal
```

I have no idea why this error happens (maybe something with the dereferencing). The error might be similar to [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101921/gdal-calc-works-but-i-get-a-python-error-at-the-end-of-each-process-that-prevent).

Comment: The script makes no sense. You can print the values of data, sizeY and sizeX. It will see why.

Comment: It's just a test setup, which creates a pixel with the value of 1. Data can be any grayscale image data.

Answer (score 1):

I had such problems with not only python gdal binds but with standard gdal apps: gdalwarp, gdal_translate and so on.. So the problem was solved after full reinstall of all gdal and python reminds in system with refreshing path and gdalpath enviroment vars. The fastest way:

1. Install Anaconda https://www.continuum.io/downloads,
2. Install GDAL core from gisinternal 
   http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php with refreshing env vars
3. From Anaconda direcory execute "conda install gdal"